# Separate real and imag parts of non-numeric expression in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Using Mathematica, I want to separate the real and imaginary parts of a non-numeric expression. MWE:

```
z = Assuming[ a \[Element] Reals && b \[Element] Reals && c \[Element] Reals && d \[Element] Reals, Expand[(a + b*I)*(c + d*I)]]
Re[z]
Im[z]
```

Is there a Mathematica function to find and display the real and imaginary components separately? e.g. a function like `GetReals[z]` would just give the output `a*c-b*d`.

Answer (score 0):

This method probably won't work in every case, but it works here.

`ComplexExpand` assumes all variables are real and expands the expression accordingly. Thus

```
ComplexExpand[(a + b*I)*(c + d*I)]
```

returns `a c - b d + I (b c + a d)` and

```
ComplexExpand[Re[(a + b*I)*(c + d*I)]]
ComplexExpand[Im[(a + b*I)*(c + d*I)]]
```

returns `a c - b d` for the first and `b c + a d` for the second.